# why am i getting segmentation fault in this?

Tags: c, recursion

I am supposed to print product of two numbers recursively.
this is my code :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int prod(int num1,int num2)
{
    if(num2=0)
    return num1;
    prod(num1+num1,num2-1);
}
int main()
{
    int n1,n2;
    printf("Enter two numbers to find their product:\n");
    scanf("%d" ,&n1);
    scanf("%d" ,&n2);
    printf("Product of %d and %d is %d",n1,n2,prod(n1,n2));
    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple code but why am i getting segmentation fault?
please help.

Comment: Did you try stepping through this code yourself with a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- You need a compare, not an assign operator.
- You need to return the recursive call.

See below:

```
int prod(int num1,int num2)
{
    if(num2 == 0)
        return num1;
    return prod(num1+num1,num2-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. You need `==` when comparing values, and you need a return on your recursive expression. As for the logic of this program, I don't believe you'll achieve a product?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int prod(int num1,int num2){
    if(num2==0){
        return num1;
    }
    return prod(num1+num1,num2-1);
}
int main(){
    int n1,n2;
    printf("Enter two numbers to find their product:\n");
    scanf("%d" ,&n1);
    scanf("%d" ,&n2);
    printf("Product of %d and %d is %d",n1,n2,prod(n1,n2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh shoot! its a typo! thank you. I know the logic is wrong. I just wanted to know why i was getting segmentation fault. It was beacuse i used "=" instead of  "==". Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

**The immediate answer:** You're overflowing the stack, e.g. you're recursing "too far". Each function invocation takes up a little bit of extra space on the call stack, and eventually you run out.

**Which leads us to the question:**
Why does your code overflow the stack? Generally, this is only an issue for fairly deep recursion, so something as simple as your example shouldn't run any risk (for small numbers).

However, paying close attention you will find that you're actually recursing *indefinitely*, because you've confused the assignment operator (`num2 = 0`) with the comparison operator (`num2 == 0`).
In C, the assignment operator evaluates to the value of the assignment, so `num2 = 0` has the value `0`. As a consequence, your condition `if (num2 = 0)` is never fulfilled, and you endlessly call `prod`.

To fix this, simply use the correct operator - `if (num2 == 0)` instead of `if (num2 = 0)`. Also, keep in mind that you'll probably want to return the result of the recursive call, otherwise you do a whole bunch of calling for nothing (e.g. `return prod(num1+num1,num2-1)`).

PS: What happens if `num2` happens to be negative?
PPS: Indentation is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

@Miket25 The code you posted actually doesn't work. If you need a complete working code that computes a correct multiplication (also in the case with num1 and num2 =0) here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int prod(int num1,int num2)  
{
    static int num_old =0;
    static int i=0;
    static int somma =0;

    if (num2==0||num1==0) {

        return(num1*num2);

    } else {

        if(num2==1)
            return somma;

        if(i==0)
            num_old =num1;

        i++;
        somma = num1+num_old;
        prod(somma,num2-1);
    }

}

int main(){
    int n1,n2;
    printf("Enter two numbers to find their product:\n");
    scanf("%d" ,&n1);
    scanf("%d" ,&n2);
    printf("Product of %d and %d is %d",n1,n2,prod(n1,n2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Vidyanshu Das this is a complete working code to obtain what you want I guess.

Comment: If you read the comment by the OP on my answer, he is aware of the logic behind his program. He even stated he wanted to know why he's getting a seg-fault. I even address the logic error on my question, did you read it to its entirety?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that a process operates in a given [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space). In simple terms, an address space is the footprint of a process. Two sections (among others) of an address space are the heap and the stack. Although implementation dependent, normally the stack section starts from the high address and eats up space (grows) to the lower addresses. The heap on the other hand generally starts from the lower addresses and grows to higher addresses. Refer to the diagram below.

```
--------------  <- high address, say 24000
|   Stack    | grows downwards when a function is called and shrinks upwards when a function returns
--------------
|            |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|            |
--------------
|    Heap    | grows upwards when memory is allocated dynamically
--------------
| Text & Data| not entirely relevant in this case
-------------- <- low address, say 2000
```

Whenever a function is called, the stack section grows downwards. Why you ask? That's because space has to be allocated for an [activation record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#ACTIVATION-RECORD). To put simply, an activation record is a block of space which packs the arguments and the local variables (and the return address as well) of a function on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

> why am i getting segmentation fault in this?

Now, back to your code. What you are doing here `if(num2=0)` is you are assigning `0` to `num2` and the assignment expression results in `0`. Hence, your condition is *always* false. As a result of which the `return` statement is never executed and you keep on calling the `prod` function. The stack section keeps growing downwards until you reach a limit when the stack can grow no further and you try to write to memory which the stack should not be accessing. This causes a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). This phenomenon is known as overflowing the stack.

Use the `==` operator to check if a number (not a `float` or `double`) is equal to another. Do this: `if (num2 == 0)`. This will cause your `return` statement to get executed (considering you don't pass a negative value in the first place) and the stack frame will shrink after you hit this [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#base_case). Thus preventing a case where you overflow the stack.

Answer (score 0):

All the codes I see in the other answers have problems.

- All don't take care of the sign of the operands.
- Some don't output the correct results.
- Some don't take care of the 0 value operands.
- One uses some static variables in the `prod()` function without initializing them at the function start, thus the function `prod()` cannot be executed more times in the same run.

I solved this issues.

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define abs(n) ( ((n)<0)?-(n):(n) )
#define sgn(n) ( ((n)<0)?-1:1 )

int prod(int num1,int num2)
{
    int s=sgn(num2),res;
    // printf("==> %d %d\n",num1,num2);

    if (!num1 || !num2)
        return 0;

    if(num2==s) {
        res=(s==-1)?-num1:num1;
        // printf("0u %d\n",res);
    } else {
        // printf("0n %d\n",num1);
        //res=(prod(num1,num2-s));
        res=(s==-1)?-num1:num1;
        res=(res+prod(num1,num2-s));
        // printf("1n %d\n",res);
    }

    return res;
}

int main(){
    int n1,n2,p;

    puts("The program terminate when the product results 0");
    do {
        printf("Enter two numbers to find their product:\n");
        scanf("%d" ,&n1);
        scanf("%d" ,&n2);

        p=prod(n1,n2);
        printf("Product of %d and %d is %d\n\n",n1,n2,p);
    } while(p);

    return 0;
}
```