# Why this program compiled successfully but failed to run?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int i=5;
    if(--i)
    {
        main();
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
```

Note that if we make `int i` as `static` then answer would be `0000`.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Recursion or static variables?

Comment: By adding static I get 0000 and that's understandable, but the problem was in loop, termination condition is not there, now I got it.

Comment: You may check my answer here as to what happens when we do an infinite recursive call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427160/why-am-i-getting-segmentation-fault-in-this/45429726#45429726

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445745/recursion-and-static-variables) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393083/unexpected-output-of-the-main-function-by-repeated-call).

Comment: Compiling successfully and then failing to run is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `i` has the value *5* every time the function `main()` is entered (each call to `main()` owns its own copy of that variable on the stack). There is no *recursion termination*, because the condition for the recursion termination is never met (i.e.: `--i` never evaluates to zero).
Therefore, `main()` is recursively called until there is no more place on the stack.

If you however declare `i` as `static`, there is a single shared copy of the variable `i` for all calls to `main()`. The recursion termination condition is met when `--i` evaluates to zero.

Answer (score 0):

It runs out of space(on stack) because it is making a call to main() indefinetely

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is correct, the program will compile without any problem. The problem is that the condition `if (--i)` will always evaluate to true as each time `main` is recursively called, a new local `i` variable is created and it is always worth `5`. As you stack more and more calls, the program will terminate by SIGSEGV when the stack can not grow anymore. You can observe this with Valgrind :

```
==10972== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10972== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10972== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10972== Command: ./a.out
==10972==
==10972== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==10972==
==10972== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
```

The reason why the program outputs `0000` when you declare `i` as a `static` variable is because `i` is not redeclared at every `main` call. So basically `main` is recursively called until `i` is worth `0`. Then, all the stacked `printf`s are executed but as `i` is worth `0` in each of these stacked calls, you will see `0000`. The `static` keyword makes all the `main` calls actually refering to the same `i` variable and not copies.